# Wemassembly set meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, webassembly

I am attempting to set a meta tag.

```
<meta name="description" content="text here"/>
```

This is what I have tried but it does not work nor does it cause any errors.

```
js.Global().Get("document").Set(`meta[name="description"]`, "new text here")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're currently doing is the same as `document["meta[name=\"description\"]"] = "new text here"` in JavaScript, which doesn't do what you seem to want.

What you need is probably along the lines of this:

```
document.querySelector(`meta[name="description"]`).content = "new text here"
```

You can use [`Call`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js?tab=doc#Value.Call) to actually select your element using `querySelector` and then set its `content` property like this:

```
js.Global().Get("document").Call("querySelector", `meta[name="description"]`).Set("content", "new text here")
```